question about prismatic F-gauges around remark 2.2.12
I am trying to get familiar with the algebraic de Rham cohomology, I am new to the topic. I am reading Bhatt's notes on prismatic F-gauges and I have few questions about intuition and details; I also write what I am not sure about. I am mostly interested in 2.2.12 and 2.2.13, these are on pages 19-20 here: https://www.math.ias.edu/~bhatt/teaching/mat549f22/lectures.pdf

Remark 2.2.12 says that $\mathcal{D}_{qc}(*/\widehat{G_a})=\mathcal{D}(k[t])$ where $t$ is a generator of the tangent space $Lie(\widehat{G_a})$. Suppose $k$ is of characteristic $0$: this allows to divide by $n!$ instead of introducing notion of divided power structure.

My attempt to unravel that: a (quasi-coherent) sheaf $\mathcal{M}$ on $*/\widehat{G_a}$ is a functor $$\mathcal{M}:\{f:Spec(R)\to \widehat{G_a}\}\mapsto \{f':M\to M\otimes Nil(R)\}$$ where $M\in Mod(R)$ and $f'(m)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty g_i(m)\otimes n^i/i!$ where $n$ is the nilpotent element classified by $f$. It turns out that $f'$ satisfying comodule axioms is equivalent to the fact that $g_i$ is equal to $n-$fold composition of $g_1$ (in particular $g_0$ is the identity).
While $\widehat{G_a}$ is not representable sheaf (since there is no "free ring on a nilpotent element") one sees that $\mathcal{M}$ is determined by an "universal comodule structure" $F':N\to N\otimes k[[q]]$ where $N$ is just a vector space. For $n\in N$ the formula $F'(n)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty G_k(n)\otimes q^k$ is actually determined by $G_1$. In other words the data of $\mathcal{M}$ boils down to an endomorphism $G_1$ of a $k-$vector space $N$: this is precisely a data of an object in $\mathcal{D}(k[t])$ (where $t$ acts as the endomorphism). Is this the idea of this remark? What is the tangent space, what is $Lie(\widehat{G_a})$ formally?
-Somehow I see that the notion of nilpotence leads to the notion of completeness, it was natural to consider $k[[q]]$ in the above. I am unable to go through details but I am guessing that this is what is happening in Proposition 2.2.13, correct? Bhatt provides a proof on abelian level. Is a higher algebra proof much more difficult, what has to be checked?
Absolutely any comments on de Rham stack are welcome!
If you know a reference where it is treated in more detail: please let me know.

I hope you aren't trying to learn about algebraic de Rham cohomology by first trying to read about prismatic F-gauges. If so, might I suggest first trying to read the more classical works of Grothendieck on the infinitesimal site and/or the work of Hartshorne? In any case, your explanation is mostly correct. Formally $\mathrm{Lie}(\widehat{G}_a)$ is the functor associating to a nilthickened $k$-algebra $R$ the kernel of $\widehat{G}_a(R)=R\to G_a(k)=k$, which is the nilradical of $R$.
